# Как изменять файл в Zip архиве

Tags: java, zip

У меня есть текстовый файл в zip архиве. Как можно редактировать этот файл, не раскрывая или не создавая новый архив (вместе с этим файлом у меня лежит еще один файл на 1 и более гб)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод конечно есть, но мальца мохнатый:

**В начале получаем данные**

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:/test.zip");
ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(name);
InputStream content = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
```

**После редактирования открываем поток записи**

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/test.zip"));
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
```

**Допустим итог у нас идет как `String result`. Далее производим преобразовав результат в массив байт**

```
byte[] buf = result.getBytes();
int len = buf.length;
zos.write(buf, 0, len);
```

**Ну и закрыть поток не забываем**

```
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();
```

[Вот англоязычный вариант этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502260/modifying-a-text-file-in-a-zip-archive-in-java)

Comment: В этом примере происходит ошибка, если новая строка отличается от старой? В англоязычном ответе что-то об этом говорилось, но я немного не понял, что они с этим сделали.

Comment: Вобще, код странный. Он говорит, что может возникнуть ошибка если размер записываемых данных отличается от старой версии. Он предлагает записывать фиксированными пакетами по 1мб. Но его условие предотвращающее ошибку IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions не имеет смысла. Метод read НЕ может записать в массив больше, чем его размер, и эта проверка на превышение размера ничего не сможет сделать.